# HTTP, HTTPS the right place to install wordpress when you have a choice

Tags: wordpress, http, https, hosting

When I install a new Wordpress site my hosting panel offers me to install it in HTTP or HTTPS space.
Should you explain which one is better and why?
I know there is a Force HTTPS option on any hosting panel, however I like to know if installing directly on HTTPS space should be a better choice, avoiding redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have SSL (HTTPS) then you must install WP in HTTPS, it means your site is secure, best for SEO purpose as well. I do not think anyone will like to install wordpress on HTTP instead of HTTPS if they have SSL.

Comment: Yes I think the same. I just deleted all My websites and cloned again directly in https space, avoiding redirection.